# Solaris C++ stream input >> operator and templates of templates

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I there a compiler option I could use in CC compiler to get the following code
(which compiles fine in Visual C++)

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> v2;
```

without the following error

> Error: "," expected instead of ">>"

Answer (score 13):

Try this :

`std::vector<std::vector<double> > v2;  //give a space between two '>'`

"`>>`" is interpreted as the right shift operator and hence you get a compile time error.

This problem will be fixed in C++0x. Have a look [**here**](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#brackets) .

Comment: Yet one more reason I can't wait for C++0x to be finalized :)

Comment: I know why is it happening. The question is why it does compile smootly in VC++. Anyway - I am after a compiler option solution to make CC more VC++ compatible - because I could not change the original source.

Comment: I think its an MSVC++ extension.

Comment: @Steve:  If you can't change the original source, and the original source is non-standard (as this is), you're in trouble.  Compilers usually have options to enable non-standard extensions, but you can't rely on it for any given extension.

Comment: MSVC++ supports many non standard extensions(eg. :  binding temporaries to  non constant references)

Answer (score 5):

You need a space between the two greater-than signs:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > v2;
```

Otherwise, the ">>" is treated as a single token.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > v2;
```

You need to add a space, other wise it will be interpreted as >> operator.